# Where is saved the order status in the database for Woocommerce

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, status, orders

I know it sounds simple, but I've researched this in many ways and only found functions to change the status of the order. I have also reviewed the whole database of wordpress I did not find the term "status" nor "processing", "completed", etc. Could anyone tell me how Woocommerce stores order status?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The status of the order is registered in `wp_post` database table under `post_status` key.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether the item've been paid or not. go to `wp_postmeta` and check whether the value `_paid_date` exist in the `meta_key` key or not.